# Grails, can't access logged in user instance from gsp

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

So here is the deal,  I have a user class secUser that `static hasMany = [pid:Process]`, also I am using spring security (not sure if it's related).

What I'm trying to do : display the drop box containing pids for the currently logged in user, had no idea how to go about it but after playing around made this

`<g:if test="${secUserInstance?.pid}">`
   `<g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="pid" name="pid" from="${secUserInstance.pid}" />`

My question is: when I put this code into the main page `/` it does nothing, however if I go to `/secUser/show/1` it shows the list of the pids belonging to the user . Can't seem to understand why it gets the info when I got to the secUser/show but doesn't anywhere else ...

P.S. I'm new to Grails and Stackoverflow but I've been stuck on this for days now and don't know where else to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your "/" path is wired to some controller in UrlMappings, in that controller there should be `static defaultAction = "list"` probably, which points to method that will handle your "/" path, or if no defaultAction set then it will be `index(){...}` method.
So that method responsible for "/" path does not pass `secUserInstance` to your "methodName".gsp file and this is why you cannot get it. While in `/secUser/show/1` you access `secUserController` `show` method wich has `[secUserInstance : secUserInstance]` or something similar and passes that object to gsp file.
You could add `secUserInstance` accessible to every page using filters linke in: [Add logged in user to context for all GSP pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965769/add-logged-in-user-to-context-for-all-gsp-pages)
Or just pass that user object in your method responsible fo '/'

Comment: Sort of a follow up, I got a filter to work but it still doesn't show anything in the root '/' but it does show stuff in all other controllers.
I'm thinking it's because '/' doesn't have a controller attached to it ...

Comment: I believe you should check UrlMappings.groovy in your conf directory and see if you have something attached to `"/"`, otherwise add `"/"(controller:"main")` or anything other that 'other' depends on where you want to route it.